# Laravel 5: TokenMismatchException while sending post ajax on mobile

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I see sometimes in logs TokenMismatchException and I noticed that this exception is thrown only for mobile users (Android, iOS) or Google Bot.

I set in meta tag csrf token and when the page is loaded I make a post ajax request. I set header in that request like that:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
 });
```

but this token is other that the one saved on the session.

Unforunately I would be able only once to reproduce this error myself on iPhone. When I loaded the page again everything was ok (even when I deleted all browser data).

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Check whether cookies are setting correctly in mobile browsers. @BartoszBialecki

Answer (score 0):

from your question my guess is it is happening because you kept the page open till the session expiry time which you defined in `/app/config/session.php`

```
'lifetime' => 480,
```

Comment: This is not the problem I think. I changed it but the error did not disappear.